# Hebrew shown gibberish in jquery array

Tags: jquery, html, character-encoding

I need some help please , [here is the link](http://yasmin-minerals.com/googlesearch1212/heb/index.html)

to my problem , hebrew language is shown as gibberish in this code! 
Please click the search button  for the exact view of the gibberish ..

Any suggestions please ?! 
Thanks

Comment: Questions should be able to stand on their own without links to external resources. Please provide html/js and the character encoding of the page within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't have this in your html header:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />`

2.Make sure you don't have two conflicting charsets

3.Open your resources (html, css, javascript) in notepad and save them with utf-8 encoding

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a correct character encoding.  [ISO 8859-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8) contains the Hebrew characters.   This should also work if you are saving your code file with `UTF-8`, which by default doesn't happen.